# Best libraries to classify misclassified categories?

Tags: python, nlp, classification, stanford-nlp, text-classification

I have a datset of over 50k rows and around 40% of the categories are misclassified categories and I want to use natural language processing to re-classify them using variables that are mostly binary or string.

Which libraries are the best to use in python for such problem? Any research papers I can read for some ideas?

Comment: I think we need a bit more detail on the problem before we'll know what papers to recommend.

Answer (score 0):

This sounds like a clear-cut example of a machine-learning classification problem. unfortunately, ML is not just something you can figure out from a library. if you want to use ML you are required to do some learning before you can skip ahead to doing this task, I recommend you read *Deep Learning with Python* which goes very quickly over the basics of machine learning and into natural language processing with the Keras library without going far into the math part. There are also many great resources from google that will teach you the basics of machine-learning and deep learning such as https://developers.google.com/machine-learning/crash-course.
But nevermind the speech, the libraries that are most common for this kind of problem are:

- Pytorch
- Tensorflow
- Keras
- Scikitlearn

I hope this helped!

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).